# WebBrowser opens link in IE instead of Default Browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, browser

So I have a WPF application that opens up a new window. Then on that new window, it creates a webBrowser object:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Source = new System.Uri(chatUrl);
browser.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(browser_Navigating);
this.browserControl.Child = browser;
```

As you can see, I have created a hook for NavigatingCancelEventHandler. Based on what I've seen, this handler is supposed to intercept links clicked within the webbrowser.

```
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```

So I take the navigation, cancel it and use the Process.Start function to open it in my default browser. The problem is, it doesn't do this. It still opens up in IE9. I've seen other threads here on StackOverflow, and they all say to do what I'm doing. But what I'm doing doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside your Navigating method to check it's actually being fired?

Comment: Just tested it and nope, my navigating method is not being fired. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the incorrect delegate type for your event handler, you're specifying a NavigatingCancelEventArgs but it should be a WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler.

Easiest way to get the right one is to just type

```
browser.Navigating +=
```

And press TAB twice, it'll generate the correct handler for you.

Edit: Hmm, I'm looking at the S.W.F version, but i'd try the above in either case for WPF.

Comment: NavigatingCancelEventArgs is the only navigating handler that intellisense can find.

Comment: Hmm, is there some property that needs setting in order to allow the event to be trapped?

Comment: No idea... thats why I'm asking here.